# Как заполнить столбец, основываясь на 3 других?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Нужно создать столбец OverAll_PassStatus и записать в него для каждого студента 'F', если студент не сдал хотя бы один из трех экзаменов, а иначе 'P'. Как это сделать? Пробовал в гугле найти - не получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот, например, хотя можно и менее заковыристо написать, наверное:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['P','F'], (10,3)))
df['OverAll_PassStatus'] = \
    df.apply(lambda x: 'PF'[any(map('F'.__eq__, x))], axis=1)
df
```

Вывод:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | OverAll_PassStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | P | F | P | F |
| 1 | P | F | P | F |
| 2 | F | F | F | F |
| 3 | F | P | F | F |
| 4 | P | P | P | P |
| 5 | P | P | P | P |
| 6 | P | F | P | F |
| 7 | F | P | F | F |
| 8 | P | F | P | F |
| 9 | P | F | F | F |

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        'A': 1,
        'B': 2,
        'C': 3
    },
    {
        'A': 4,
        'B': 5,
        'C': 6
    },
    {
        'A': 7,
        'B': 8,
        'C': 9
    },
    {
        'A': 10,
        'B': 11,
        'C': 12
    },
    {
        'A': 1,
        'B': 2,
        'C': 3
    },
]

def mult(y):
    a, b, c = y
    return a * b * c

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['D'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(mult, axis=1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]